# Shutdown on opening laptop lid due to acpi detecting high temperature

Tags: 20.04, shutdown, acpi

I have ASUS ROG GL503E running ubuntu dual booted with windows. On Ubuntu almost always on opening my laptop lid acpi detects temperature to be 100 C and shuts down the machine, even though physically the machine is not warm at all. This only happens on Ubuntu and not on Windows. That is why I suspect this to be a software issue than a hardware one. Could this be due to an acpi bug? I also upgraded my BIOS firmware but that didn't help.